# Update/Delete XML node(tags) in SCALA

Tags: xml, scala

```
val pets = 
<Pet>
<Cat>black
<Kitty>small</Kitty>
<Kitty>big</Kitty>
<Kitty>large</Kitty>
</Cat>
<Dog>grey
<Kitty>large</Kitty>
</Dog>
</Pet>
```

Here, i need to change(update/delete) `<Kitty>{text}</Kitty>` of child Node "Cat" as `<baby>{text}</baby>` in scala!

So far i have tried this,

```
class xml_class{
    def replace(elem:Elem):Elem=elem.copy(
      child = elem.child.map{
         case elem: Elem if elem.label=="Cat" => <Kitty>{elem}</Kitty>
         case elem: Elem => replace(elem)
         case other => other
       }
    )}

var ob =new xml_class()
println(ob.replace(pets))
```

which gives output as,

```
<Pet>
<Cat>black
<baby>small</baby>
<baby>big</baby>
<baby>large</baby>
</Cat>
<Dog>grey
<baby>large</baby>
</Dog>
</Pet>
```

So it actually changes all the `<kitty>` tags in both `<Cat> & <Dog>`, whereas i need to change that only on `<Cat>` based on XPATH condition or whatsoever.

Comment: What have you tried before yourself? We can help you finding errors in your tries, this is not a place to do your work

Comment: @MarvinFischer Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you need to change the `Cat` child label from `Kitty` to `baby`.

```
class xml_class {
    def replace(elem: Elem): Elem = {
      elem.copy(child = elem.child.map {
        case catEle: Elem if catEle.label == "Cat" =>
          catEle.copy(child = catEle.child.map {
            case cc: Elem if cc.label == "Kitty" => cc.copy(label = "baby")
            case innerOther => innerOther
          })
        case other => other
      })
    }
  }
```

Output looks like:

```
<Pet>
      <Cat>black
        <baby>small</baby>
        <baby>big</baby>
        <baby>large</baby>
      </Cat>
      <Dog>grey
        <Kitty>large</Kitty>
      </Dog>
    </Pet>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rumesh
By the way, how to do the same using XPATH

Comment: replace `cc.copy(label = "baby")` with `<baby>{cc.text}</baby>`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Rumesh You are hard coding everything inside the function, in the case if i need to change the label of XPATH `Pet\"Cat"\"Kitty"` as "baby" how to do that without hardcoding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: using XPATH `NodeSeq.fromSeq((elem \ "Cat" \ "Kitty").map(_.asInstanceOf[Elem].copy(label = "baby")))` you can get the `Cat` tag field, you can't change root field `Pet`

Answer (score 0):

The scala-xml library has a way to define rewrite rules:

```
val kittyToBabyRule = new scala.xml.transform.RewriteRule {
  override def transform(n: Node): Seq[Node] = n match {
    case <Kitty>{text}</Kitty> => <baby>{text}</baby>
    case _ => n
  }
}

val kittyTransformer = new scala.xml.transform.RuleTransformer(kittyToBabyRule)
```

Then you can use the rewrite rule in a rewrite rule:

```
val catRule = new scala.xml.transform.RewriteRule {
  override def transform(n: Node): Seq[Node] = n match {
    case e: Elem if e.label == "Cat" => kittyTransformer(n)
    case _ => n
  }
}
```

Then you can create a transformer with the top-level rule:

```
val catTransformer = new scala.xml.transform.RuleTransformer(catRule)
```

Then you can run the transformer as:

```
scala> catTransformer(doc)
res0: scala.xml.Node =
<Pet>
<Cat>black
<baby>small</baby>
<baby>big</baby>
<baby>large</baby>
</Cat>
<Dog>grey
<Kitty>large</Kitty>
</Dog>
</Pet>
```

Comment: Actually your code changes all the existence of the "Kitty" in the XML

Comment: Oh, ok.  I see you wrote what your program output.  Next time, you should have put what output you were expecting.